# Clear input search box and refresh data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

In this code, the `#searchInpForm` search box gets cleared but the data that is called by my `getAllPersonnel()` function doesn't refresh. It refreshes if I don't include the line about emptying the search box.

Also, the function gets called but the data just doesn't. I have the same issue if I set the search input field to an empty string as well. What should I look at next to fix this?

```js
$("#refreshBtn").click(function () {
  if ($("#personnelBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    // console.log("Button was clicked");
    $("#searchInpForm")[0].reset();
    getAllPersonnel();

    // $("#searchInp").val("");
  } else if ($("#departmentsBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    // console.log("Button was clicked");
    getAllDepartments();
  } else if ($("#locationsBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    getAllLocations();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the content of the `getAllPersonnel()` method

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, unfortunately the setTimeout and putting the getAllPersonnel function first don't make a difference. Also, I noticed the rows all come back when I start typing in the box. Either a backspace (there is nothing to backspace) or any letter. Weirdly, a row that I have set to display: none also shows up but doesn't show up when the table initially loads :( Is there a clue here?

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? Why is your question tagged with SQL, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `getAllPersonnel()` function is using the `searchInpForm` value. So if you clear it first, the function won't work/refresh. Try to clear it only after function is called, like below.

```
$("#refreshBtn").click(function () {
  if ($("#personnelBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    // console.log("Button was clicked");
    getAllPersonnel();
    $("#searchInpForm")[0].reset();

    // $("#searchInp").val("");
  } else if ($("#departmentsBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    // console.log("Button was clicked");
    getAllDepartments();
  } else if ($("#locationsBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    getAllLocations();
  }
});
```

Or, clear it after a few milliseconds.

```
$("#refreshBtn").click(function () {
  if ($("#personnelBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    // console.log("Button was clicked");
    getAllPersonnel();
    setTimeout(function(){$("#searchInpForm")[0].reset();},300);
    
    // $("#searchInp").val("");
  } else if ($("#departmentsBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    // console.log("Button was clicked");
    getAllDepartments();
  } else if ($("#locationsBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    getAllLocations();
  }
});
```

````
    ```
const getAllPersonnel = () => {
  initiateAjaxRequest("libs/php/getAll.php", "GET", callbackGetAllPersonnel);
};

const callbackGetAllPersonnel = (result) => {
  // console.log(`Personnel: ${JSON.stringify(result.data)}`);
  // console.log(`personnel function was called`);

  $("#personnel-tab-pane tbody tr").not("#pers-row").remove();
  const data = result.data;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const newRow = $("#pers-row").clone(true);
    newRow.attr("id", `pers-row-${i}`);
    newRow.attr("data-id", `${data[i].id}`);
    newRow.find(".editPersonnelBtn").attr("data-id", `${data[i].id}`);
    newRow.find(".deletePersonnelBtn").attr("data-id", `${data[i].id}`);
    newRow.find(".pers-name").text(`${data[i].lastName}, ${data[i].firstName}`);
    newRow.find(".pers-job-title").text(`${data[i].jobTitle}`);
    newRow.find(".pers-location").text(`${data[i].location}`);
    newRow.find(".pers-email").text(`${data[i].email}`);

    $("#personnel-tab-pane").find("tbody").append(newRow);
  }
};
````

````
$("#searchInp").on("keyup", function () {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#personnel-tab-pane tbody tr").filter(function () {
    // Assuming you want to search across all columns in a row
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
  });
});```
````

Comment: Thanks @yeyene, the searchInp is filtering the table inside the personnel-tab-pane. The rows get deleted and repopulated in the getAllPersonnel function. Maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: Try to not clear the #searchInpForm value as soon as #refreshBtn button click, only clear it after  appending loop in callbackGetAllPersonnel function

Answer (score 0):

You are emptying the search box before you apply the search. Switch the order of the operations:

```
    getAllPersonnel();
    $("#searchInpForm")[0].reset();
```

Also, it would make sense to get the value/text of your search and pass it to `getAllPersonnel`, so it will rely on the search you have given it, instead of what the UI button has. This way your UI will not mess around in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was something to do with the classes I was using. So because I used the same class for the original row (the empty hidden one) and for the cloned rows that I filled with data, it was coming up in the search and not staying hidden. Also, in the #searchInp, I was just using tr to identify what to filter. When I changed it to use the class name it all worked fine.